# AngularJS, IONIC [$compile:ctreq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have an AngularJS application, where I use directive **ion-side-menu** along with **ion-side-menus** from **Ionic, v1.0.0-beta.12**

```
HTML DOM
<ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu side="left" ng-class="{ 'open': isLeftDesktopSidebarOpen() }">
            <ion-content has-header="false">
                <div eb-left-menu></div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>


        <!-- -->

        <ion-side-menu side="right" ng-class="{'open': isRightDesktopSidebarOpen()}">
            <ion-content has-header="false">
                <div eb-right-menu></div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>


JS Script
<div class="eb-ion-side-menus-container">
    <ion-side-menus class="eb-ion-side-menus">
        <!-- Center content -->
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content edge-drag-threshold="true">
            <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-mainsubheader" eb-center-div ng-show="loggedIn">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon pull-left" ng-click="openLeftSidebar();"></button>
                <span class="hidden-large-inline">
                    <button style="line-height: 33px;font-size: 17px;margin-top: -5px !important;width: 154px;background-size: 30px !important;height: 40px;" class="button button-icon button-clear eb-ico logo_small" ng-click="gotoMain()"></button>
                </span>
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-grid pull-right" ng-click="openRightSidebar();"></button>
            </div>

            <ion-content class="eb-main-content">
                <div ui-view id="main" autoscroll="false" class="animate-on am-fade-and-scale"></div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
    </ion-side-menus>

        <!-- Left menu -->
    <ion-side-menus>  
        <ion-side-menu side="left" ng-class="{ 'open': isLeftMenuOpen() }">
            <div class="bar bar-on-menu bar-subheader bar-mainsubheader" ng-click="toggleLeftSidebar();" ng-show="loggedIn">
                <h1 class="title">
                    <span ng-click="closeLeftSidebar();" style="cursor:pointer; width: 190px;display: inline-block;">Menu</span>
                    <button style="position: absolute;top: 5px;right: 5px;" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="closeLeftSidebar();"></button>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <ion-content has-header="false">
                <div eb-left-menu></div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>

<!-- -->
        <ion-side-menus>
            <ion-side-menu side="right" ng-class="{'open': isRightMenuOpen() }">
                <div class="bar bar-on-menu bar-subheader bar-mainsubheader" ng-click="toggleRightSidebar();" ng-show="loggedIn">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        <span ng-click="closeRightSidebar();" style="cursor:pointer; width: 190px;display: inline-block;">Moje aplikacje</span>
                        <button style="position: absolute;top: 5px;left: 5px;" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-grid" ng-click="closeRightSidebar();"></button>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <ion-content has-header="false">
                    <div eb-right-menu></div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-side-menu>
        </ion-side-menus>
</div>
```

Its purpose is to toggle a side bar, once clicked.
And it does work, however it gives me an error in `Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/$compile/ctreq?p0=ionSideMenus&p1=ionSideMenu`

Description of error says

> Controller 'ionSideMenus', required by directive 'ionSideMenu', can't be found!

However it does exist in my vendor file(where I keep all frameworks and libraries)

I would really appreciate some help :D

#### UPDATED 25.05

I think it's also worth mentioning, that the above problem occurs iff I display my page in a desktop view. Otherwise, when emulated via Google Chrome to either Android or Ios it works just fine.

Comment: It looks like you have in your HTML ionSideMenus directive missing like `ul >li`, here you have to `ion-side-menus > ion-side-menu`

Comment: You need to wrap them in `<ion-side-menus>`

Comment: I have placed both my <ion-side-menu> inside of one <ion-side-menus> and it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to wrap ion-side-menu inside of ion-side-menus

so your code will look like this.

```
<ion-side-menus><ion-side-menu side="left" ng-class="{ 'open': isLeftMenuOpen() }">
        <div class="bar bar-on-menu bar-subheader bar-mainsubheader" ng-click="toggleLeftSidebar();" ng-show="loggedIn">
            <h1 class="title">
                <span ng-click="closeLeftSidebar();" style="cursor:pointer; width: 190px;display: inline-block;">Menu</span>
                <button style="position: absolute;top: 5px;right: 5px;" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="closeLeftSidebar();"></button>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <ion-content has-header="false">
            <div eb-left-menu></div>
        </ion-content>

    </ion-side-menu></ion-side-menus>
```

You can find details here

[Click here to check it](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ionSideMenus&p1=ionSideMenu)

Comment: Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: I changed my answer. i tested this code and it works.

Comment: I didn't work for me. An aspect I didn't mention until now is that I use <ion-side-menu> twice, one under another. Tried wrapping them both in one <ion-side-menus> as well as wrapping them individualy

Comment: can you update your question and post the full code you have? do you have it like this? <ion-side-menus>
 <!-- Main content -->
 <ion-side-menu-content>

 </ion-side-menu-content>
 
 <!-- Left Side Menu -->
 <ion-side-menu side="left">
 
 </ion-side-menu>
 
 <!-- Right Side Menu -->
 <ion-side-menu side="right">
 
 </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

Comment: Yunus Saha, the question has been updated. Excuse me for the long pause.